# How to re-enable an event handler?

Tags: jquery

I have a link with an empty href, because this href is dynamic. It requires some Ajax call so I want to populate the href attribute only when the user needs it, meaning when the link is clicked. When the href is set, it doesn't change anymore for the page.

```
$('#myLink').one('click', function(e) {
    if ($('#myLink').attr('href') == '') {
        var that = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        someFunctionWithAjaxCallAndCallback(function(pCallbackReturn) {
            // ... callbak function with some logic
            $(that).off('click').click();
        });
    }
});
```

The thing is the href is populated correctly, I can manually click on the link and it works, BUT the jQuery code that is supposed to "cancel" the preventDefault(), ie. to open that link, doesn't work, nothing happens for $(that).off('click').click(); (and no errors in the console).

I use jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

I also tried different combinations of .trigger('click') instead of .click(), and $('#myLink') instead of $(that)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing instead of $(that).off('click').click();:

```
$('#myLink').off('click');
$('#myLink')[0].click();
```

Comment: should be able to shorten to`$("#myLink").off("click")[0].click()`